# WPF - Making hyperlinks clickable

Tags: wpf, url, hyperlink

I've got a bit of text that I'm trying to display in a list.  Some of those pieces of a text contain a hyperlink.  I'd like to make the links clickable within the text.  I can imagine solutions to this problem, but they sure don't seem pretty.

For instance, I could tear apart the string, splitting it into hyperlinks and non-hyperlinks.  Then I could dynamically build a Textblock, adding plain text elements and hyperlink objects as appropriate.

I'm hoping there's a better, preferably something declarative.

Example: "Hey, check out this link: http://mylink.com  It's really cool."

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You need something that will parse the Text of the TextBlock and create the all the inline objects at runtime. For this you can either create your own custom control derived from TextBlock or an attached property.

For the parsing, you can search for URLs in the text with a regular expression. I borrowed a regular expression from [A good url regular expression?](https://web.archive.org/web/20210126191109/http://geekswithblogs.net/casualjim/archive/2005/12/01/61722.aspx) but there are others available on the web, so you can choose the one which works best for you.

In the sample below, I used an attached property. To use it, modify your TextBlock to use NavigateService.Text instead of Text property:

```
<Window x:Class="DynamicNavigation.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DynamicNavigation"
    Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
    <StackPanel>
        <!-- Type something here to see it displayed in the TextBlock below -->
        <TextBox x:Name="url"/>
        
        <!-- Dynamically updates to display the text typed in the TextBox -->
        <TextBlock local:NavigationService.Text="{Binding Text, ElementName=url}" />
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

The code for the attached property is given below:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;

namespace DynamicNavigation
{
    public static class NavigationService
    {
        // Copied from http://geekswithblogs.net/casualjim/archive/2005/12/01/61722.aspx
        private static readonly Regex RE_URL = new Regex(@"(?#Protocol)(?:(?:ht|f)tp(?:s?)\:\/\/|~/|/)?(?#Username:Password)(?:\w+:\w+@)?(?#Subdomains)(?:(?:[-\w]+\.)+(?#TopLevel Domains)(?:com|org|net|gov|mil|biz|info|mobi|name|aero|jobs|museum|travel|[a-z]{2}))(?#Port)(?::[\d]{1,5})?(?#Directories)(?:(?:(?:/(?:[-\w~!$+|.,=]|%[a-f\d]{2})+)+|/)+|\?|#)?(?#Query)(?:(?:\?(?:[-\w~!$+|.,*:]|%[a-f\d{2}])+=(?:[-\w~!$+|.,*:=]|%[a-f\d]{2})*)(?:&(?:[-\w~!$+|.,*:]|%[a-f\d{2}])+=(?:[-\w~!$+|.,*:=]|%[a-f\d]{2})*)*)*(?#Anchor)(?:#(?:[-\w~!$+|.,*:=]|%[a-f\d]{2})*)?");
        
        public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "Text",
            typeof(string),
            typeof(NavigationService),
            new PropertyMetadata(null, OnTextChanged)
        );

        public static string GetText(DependencyObject d)
        { return d.GetValue(TextProperty) as string; }
        
        public static void SetText(DependencyObject d, string value)
        { d.SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
        
        private static void OnTextChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var text_block = d as TextBlock;
            if (text_block == null)
                return;
                
            text_block.Inlines.Clear();

            var new_text = (string)e.NewValue;
            if ( string.IsNullOrEmpty(new_text) )
                return;
                
            // Find all URLs using a regular expression
            int last_pos = 0;
            foreach (Match match in RE_URL.Matches(new_text))
            {
                // Copy raw string from the last position up to the match
                if (match.Index != last_pos)
                {
                    var raw_text = new_text.Substring(last_pos, match.Index - last_pos);
                    text_block.Inlines.Add(new Run(raw_text));
                }
                
                // Create a hyperlink for the match
                var link = new Hyperlink(new Run(match.Value))
                {
                    NavigateUri = new Uri(match.Value)
                };
                link.Click += OnUrlClick;
                
                text_block.Inlines.Add(link);
                
                // Update the last matched position
                last_pos = match.Index + match.Length;
            }
            
            // Finally, copy the remainder of the string
            if (last_pos < new_text.Length)
                text_block.Inlines.Add(new Run(new_text.Substring(last_pos)));
        }

        private static void OnUrlClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var link = (Hyperlink)sender;
            // Do something with link.NavigateUri like:
            Process.Start(link.NavigateUri.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome, exactly what I was looking for.  Gave me a whole new way to look at some of the WPF problems I've been facing, too.

Comment: Wonderful! I put the VB version of this answer below.

Comment: One minor issue is that if the protocol is not specified (eg. I just type in www.google.com), the component throws an exception when trying to create the Uri (UriFormatException - "Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined.")

Answer (score 11):

Here is the simplified version:

```
<TextBlock>
    Hey, check out this link:        
    <Hyperlink NavigateUri="CNN.COM" Click="cnn_Click">Test</Hyperlink>
</TextBlock>
```

Answer (score 4):

Something like this?

```
<TextBlock>
    <TextBlock Text="Hey, check out this link:"/>
    <Hyperlink NavigateUri={Binding ElementName=lvTopics, Path=SelectedValue.Title}
                           Click="Url_Click">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Text="Feed: " FontWeight="Bold"/>
            <TextBlock Text={Binding ElementName=lvTopics, Path=SelectedValue.Url}/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Hyperlink>
</TextBlock>
```

EDIT: If you need dynamic, bind it. In the example above, lvTopics(not shown) is bound to a list of objects with Title and Url properties.
Also, it will not go to the url automatically, you need to handle it with a similar code:

```
private void Url_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{    browser.Navigate(((Hyperlink)sender).NavigateUri); }
```

I just wanted to show that you can embed anything into TextBlock, including Hyperlink, and anything into Hyperlink.

Comment: Uh, yeah, but the question is how to turn the plain text INTO what you supplied here.  It's a data feed, this needs to happen dynamically.

Answer (score 2):

The VB.Net version of Bojan's answer. I improved a little upon it: This code will parse an url like http://support.mycompany.com?username=x&password=y to an inline of http://support.mycompany.com, while still navigating to the full url with username and password

```
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions
Imports System.Windows
Imports System.Windows.Controls
Imports System.Windows.Documents

Public Class NavigationService
    ' Copied from http://geekswithblogs.net/casualjim/archive/2005/12/01/61722.aspx '
    Private Shared ReadOnly RE_URL = New Regex("(?#Protocol)(?<domainURL>(?:(?:ht|f)tp(?:s?)\:\/\/|~/|/)?(?#Username:Password)(?:\w+:\w+@)?(?#Subdomains)(?:(?:[-\w]+\.)+(?#TopLevel Domains)(?:com|org|net|gov|mil|biz|info|mobi|name|aero|jobs|museum|travel|[a-z]{2})))(?#Port)(?::[\d]{1,5})?(?#Directories)(?:(?:(?:/(?:[-\w~!$+|.,=]|%[a-f\d]{2})+)+|/)+|\?|#)?(?#Query)(?:(?:\?(?:[-\w~!$+|.,*:]|%[a-f\d{2}])+=(?:[-\w~!$+|.,*:=]|%[a-f\d]{2})*)(?:&(?:[-\w~!$+|.,*:]|%[a-f\d{2}])+=(?:[-\w~!$+|.,*:=]|%[a-f\d]{2})*)*)*(?#Anchor)(?:#(?:[-\w~!$+|.,*:=]|%[a-f\d]{2})*)?")

    Public Shared ReadOnly TextProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached( _
        "Text",
        GetType(String),
        GetType(NavigationService),
        New PropertyMetadata(Nothing, AddressOf OnTextChanged)
    )

    Public Shared Function GetText(d As DependencyObject) As String
        Return TryCast(d.GetValue(TextProperty), String)
    End Function

    Public Shared Sub SetText(d As DependencyObject, value As String)
        d.SetValue(TextProperty, value)
    End Sub

    Private Shared Sub OnTextChanged(d As DependencyObject, e As DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)
        Dim text_block = TryCast(d, TextBlock)
        If text_block Is Nothing Then Return

        text_block.Inlines.Clear()

        Dim new_text = CStr(e.NewValue)
        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(new_text) Then Return

        ' Find all URLs using a regular expression '
        Dim last_pos As Integer = 0
        For Each match As Match In RE_URL.Matches(new_text)
            'Copy raw string from the last position up to the match '
            If match.Index <> last_pos Then
                Dim raw_text = new_text.Substring(last_pos, match.Index - last_pos)
                text_block.Inlines.Add(New Run(raw_text))
            End If

            ' Create a hyperlink for the match '
            Dim link = New Hyperlink(New Run(match.Groups("domainURL").Value)) With
                {
                    .NavigateUri = New Uri(match.Value)
                }
            AddHandler link.Click, AddressOf OnUrlClick

            text_block.Inlines.Add(link)

            'Update the last matched position '
            last_pos = match.Index + match.Length
        Next

        ' Finally, copy the remainder of the string '
        If last_pos < new_text.Length Then
            text_block.Inlines.Add(New Run(new_text.Substring(last_pos)))
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Shared Sub OnUrlClick(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
        Try
            Dim link = CType(sender, Hyperlink)
            Process.Start(link.NavigateUri.ToString)
        Catch
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using something like MVVM light or similar architecture, you could have a interaction trigger on textblock mousedown property and do whatever in the viewmodel's code.