# How to make the URL in textblock be clickable?

Tags: silverlight

The content of the textblock is imported from a web service, but somehow there is a URL.

Is it possible to make it a link?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you looked at this question?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/861409/wpf-making-hyperlinks-clickable

It seems to achieve what you need.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you want [a LinkLabel control](http://www.codeplex.com/SilverlightLinkLabel). I've used that control with some modifications in my [Silverlight Twitter Badge](http://www.codeplex.com/Twilight) to mix the text and links that show up in tweets.

If you just have a TextBlock with a link only and want that clickable then you just set the cursor to be a hand and add an event handler for the MouseLeftButtonDown event that would navigate to the value of the TextBox.

Xaml:

```
<TextBlock Text="http://www.microsoft.com" Cursor="Hand" TextDecorations="Underline" MouseLeftButtonDown="TextBlock_MouseLeftButtonDown" />
```

Code:

```
private void TextBlock_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    var txt = ((TextBlock)sender).Text;
    System.Windows.Browser.HtmlPage.Window.Navigate(new Uri(txt, UriKind.Absolute));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like the following; however this makes use of a Label and not a textblock.

In your XAML you do the following:

```
<dataInput:Label Grid.Row="2">
                <ContentPresenter>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="Hello world"/>
                        <HyperlinkButton x:Name="Test" NavigateUri="{Binding Path=URI}" Content="This is a url"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </ContentPresenter>
            </dataInput:Label>
```

and in your code behind you add the following dependency property and set the datacontext to the page itself

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty URLProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("URI", typeof(Uri), typeof(MainPage), null);

        public Uri URI { get
            {
                return (Uri)GetValue(URLProperty);
            }
            set
            { SetValue(URLProperty, value); }
        }
```

This code sets the dependency property for the binding to the URL;

```
public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            URI = new Uri("/Home", UriKind.Relative);
            DataContext = this;
        }
```

This code creates a new URI and binds it to the variable. It also sets the data context to the page itself.