# Making URLs on a textblock clickable

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, hyperlink, textblock

I'm programming a little Twitter Client just for fun. I have the tweet's text on a `TextBlock` and I want to make the URLs clickable.

I know that I have to parse the URLs with a regexp but... how I put text plus link on the `TextBlock`?

I can't have a string like: `Hello check my blog at <Hyperlink>http​://myblogurl.com</Hyperlink>` because the `TextBlock` doesn't parse the tags.

Then, how I can have a `TextBlock` that maybe has a link or maybe not?

Thank you.

Comment: Did you read this question?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/861409/wpf-making-hyperlinks-clickable/867455#867455

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<RichTextBox  IsDocumentEnabled="True">
        <FlowDocument>
          <Paragraph>
          This is a richTextBox. And this is a <Hyperlink NavigateUri="http://www.microsoft.com">Hyperlink</Hyperlink>.
          </Paragraph>
        </FlowDocument>
  </RichTextBox>
```

[MSDN discussion](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/7202b152-2c4f-4b06-8ebf-474f193d7db9/)

Answer (score 1):

Rather than use a TextBlock, take a look at using the WPF version of the RichTextBox. It's a very flexible little critter.

Answer (score 1):

Something like...

```
<TextBlock>
    <Hyperlink Name="btnOpen" Click="btnOpen_Click">
        <TextBlock Text="Click to Open" />
    </Hyperlink>
</TextBlock>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could parse the string in code behind and build up a collection of content controls, change your textblock to a wrap panel and set the children of the panel to your collection you have created.