# WP7 Silverlight: How to make the links in a textblock clickable?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

I know this question has been asked before, but the other answers don't work for me because I'm on Windows Phone 7.

I have a `TextBlock` whose `Text` is not known until runtime. I need to make all links clickable. My approach is basically the one described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/861409/wpf-making-hyperlinks-clickable/867455#867455), but there is no `Hyperlink` class in the WP7 SDK and I can't add a `HyperlinkButton` to `textBlock.Inlines`. Am I doing something wrong, or do I need a different approach?

Answer (score 2):

WrapPanel with TextBlocks and HyperlinkButtons has been a pattern used for this problem on the phone platform.

Comment: Ok, and is there a way to make the `HyperlinkButton` automatically open a `WebBrowserTask` on tap, or must I wire that up manually?

Comment: This thread covers that topic well... http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsphone7series/thread/98fefb30-a9f9-4a5f-9942-6965cb2f2e3c