# Is there a way to have a HyperlinkButton inside a block of TextBlock? (windows phone 7)

Tags: windows-phone-7, silverlight-3.0

I have a big block of text and I want to have a hyperlink "embedded" inside it.  Something like [this](http://example.com) - akin to an html a tag.

I'm assuming there's an easy way to do this with the HyperlinkButton in Windows Phone 7 and  - Silverlight just didn't find it...

Comment: possible duplicate of [WP7 Silverlight: How to make the links in a textblock clickable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4544761/wp7-silverlight-how-to-make-the-links-in-a-textblock-clickable)

Answer (score 0):

There's not really a good way that I know of - the typical way of doing this is to use a WrapPanel (in the SL for Windows Phone Toolkit), and fill it with TextBlock and HyperlinkButton elements.

Silverlight 4 in a web browser (on a desktop PC/Mac) has RichTextBox which has a Hyperlink element that can be inline with text, so if you're also doing SL stuff for the desktop, that's a much better way to do it there.