# Clickable links in fetched tweets C#

Tags: c#, xaml, twitter, hyperlink

I have a problem which I do not know how to solve exactly like I'd like it to be solved. I pull tweets from certain twitter feeds such as users and # (via .rss search). However, some of the tweets contains a link, which isn't click able when it's shown in the ListBox (datatemplate). Is there an easy way to convert everything within each individual tweet which contains "http://<-link->" into an actual click able link? Either via XAML or C#.

Answer (score 0):

Relatively easy, in C#:

1. Pull the URL out with a Regex (example regex here: [What is the best regular expression to check if a string is a valid URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161738/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-url))
2. Wrap the URL in an `<a>` tag and point the `href` to the URL
3. Replace the original URL in the tweet with the composed anchor tag

Comment: Hm - I'm not using HTML for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

In case you don't have predefined text (and you don't) you need to parse tweet text to find hyperlink and to replace raw text with hyperlink `Run`. See below link for example:

[WPF - Making hyperlinks clickable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/861409/wpf-making-hyperlinks-clickable)

Comment: Sadly, the WinRT API doesn't support "Hyperlink"

Answer (score 0):

I found the [HtmlTextBlock](https://github.com/sinelaw/HtmlTextBlock) control useful. It is:

> A WPF TextBlock that can parse a limited set of HTML tags and display them (originally a project by Leung Yat Chun on CodeProject.com)

The only problem in your case is that the tags are in a different format than true HTML, you have to write them with square brackets (`[]`) rather than angle ones (`<>`).

The original [version of the code on CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33196/WPF-Html-supported-TextBlock) is not the latest, I had to do some searching and eventually put it up as a [github repository](https://github.com/sinelaw/HtmlTextBlock) since it is open source (and with the owner's blessing) - as the repo readme mentions, the code is not mine.