# Dynamically Bound TextBlock Links Not Active until Clicked

Tags: wpf

I'm dynamically binding a Textblock (in a ListBox if that matters) and creating hyperlinks if the text contains urls. I'm using the technique as show in [WPF - Making hyperlinks clickable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/861409/wpf-making-hyperlinks-clickable)

Works great but the weird thing is everytime I update the binding with new text the new hyperlinks are not clickable until I actually click on the textblock. Even the "hand cursor", indicating a link does not work until I click on the textblock.

The app does not lose focus, it still receives key strokes. I've tried setting focus and sending key clicks with no luck. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's hacky but it was the only thing that seemed to work.

I sent a KeyUp (down arrow) to the application and all is good.

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern void keybd_event(byte bVk, byte bScan, uint dwFlags, uint dwExtraInfo);
```

and then in the textchanged handler at the end.

```
textBlock.Inlines.Clear();
textBlock.Inlines.AddRange(inlines);
keybd_event(0x28, 0, 0x0002, 0);
```

There's something about the application having to see an input event allows the it to recoginize the textblock has been with new wpf controls.